# Ruby on Rails i18n - Want To Translate Custom Messages in Models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, error-handling, localization, internationalization, message

I have attributes with special validation where I use the message clause to display a special message just for that validation.  Here is one example:

```
validates :email, presence:   true, length: { maximum: 60 },
                format:     { with: valid_email_regex, message: "is not a valid email address format." },
                uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
```

I would like to translate the message here but I am not sure how to do it.

I have seen examples where they type something like this: message: t("some_value_here").  I'm not sure about the designation.  I tried something like this message: t(:bad_email).  I did the following in my yaml file just to try something.

```
activemodel:
  errors:
    bad_email: "is not a valid email address format."
```

When I tried to access my Rails application I got the following error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `t' for #<Class:0x007fefc1b709e0>)
```

I also tried this in my yaml file:

```
activemodel:
  errors:
    user:
      bad_email: "is not a valid email address format."
```

I have been researching this off and on all day long.  All I can find is to replace built-in error hashes like blank or empty.  Is there a way for me to have custom error hashes and replace them in the model?  At this point I cannot get the t to work as coded.  My hope is that the problem is how I have my yaml file set up.  I have seen varying versions of how to set this up.  I am not sure if I should put this under activemodel or activerecord. I assumed activemodel since that is where the custom message is that I want to translate.

Any help would be appreciated.  This is the last piece I need to figure out before launching my first translation of the application.

**UPDATE 7/29/2013 7:30 pm CDT**

**bgates** gave me a very good start with how to setup my model files to receive the custom message in the YAML file.  However I ended up having to do the following setup in my yaml file for the custom messages to be found.

```
activerecord:
  errors: 
    models: 
      user: 
        attributes: 
          bio: 
            no_links: "cannot contain email addresses or website links (URLs)."
          email: 
            bad_email: "is not a valid email address format."
          username: 
            bad_username: "can only contain numbers and letters.  No special characters or spaces."
```

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Use a symbol for the message:

```
validates :email, presence:   true, length: { maximum: 60 },
            format:     { with: valid_email_regex, message: :bad_email },
            uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
```

then in the yaml file

```
[lang]:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      messages:
        bad_email: "just ain't right"
```

If there's a translation specific to this model, it will override the general one above:

```
[lang]:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      models:
        model_name: # or namespace/model_name
          attributes:
            email:
              bad_email: "model-specific message for invalid email"
```

If you write custom validations, `add_error(:email, :bad_email)` will do the lookup above, but `errors[:email] << :bad_email` will not.

Comment: I setup my model and yaml files.  I got a missing translation for activerecord.errors.models.user.attributes.email.bad_email.  I put the change I made in my yaml file in my description.  It's working well.  THANKS SO MUCH FOR HELPING ME GET STARTED.

Comment: I had to use `activemodel` instead of `activerecord` as my top-level key. More details can be found in the Errors [source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/ccbc98e37dcc11ad5150b93dcee8008bc94aa83a/activemodel/lib/active_model/errors.rb#L465-L472).

Answer (score 29):

I just walked through all this and found the [rails guides for custom validators](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#performing-custom-validations) too hard-coded... I'm posting this here even though it's not exactly what you asked, but the Q title fits perfectly (which is why I read this post for my problem).

Custom validation with i18n message:

```
validate :something_custom?, if: :some_trigger_condition

def something_custom?
  if some_error_condition
    errors.add(:some_field_key, :some_custom_msg)
  end
end

# en.yml
activerecord: 
  errors:
    models:
      some_model:
        some_custom_msg: "This is i18n controlled. yay!"
```

Answer (score 4):

The solution to this does not need to be custom; The `format` validator message already maps to the `:invalid` symbol. You need only set the invalid in translation.

```
en:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      models:
        some_model:
          attributes:
            email:
              invalid: "FOO"
```

Reference: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#error-message-interpolation

Answer (score 1):

I will give a complete example.

To make your models cleaner, you *can* create a custom validation helper method in an entirely new directory - `app/validations`, which will be autoloaded by Rails.

I'll call my file `time_validator.rb`, located at `app/validations/time_validator.rb`

My file has the following code, which validates user-entered time - that it is *actually* time.

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

class TimeValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    Time.parse(value).strftime('%H:%M')
  rescue ArgumentError 
    record.errors.add(attribute, :invalid_time)
  end
end
```

You can read more about creating custom ActiveRecord validations [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-validators)

Our main point of concern is the `record.errors` line. Note that it's `attribute` and not `:attribute`, where `attribute` is the column in your model.

`:invalid_time` is the key that retrieves your translated content from your locales file. In my case, this is the `en` file:

```
en
  activerecord:
    errors:
      models:
        home:
          attributes:
            check_in_time:
              invalid_time: Please enter valid time
            check_out_time:
              invalid_time: Please enter valid time
```

Then in the `home` model:

```
validates :check_in_time, time: { allow_blank: true }
validates :check_out_time, time: { allow_blank: true }
```

`time` automatically gets mapped to the class `TimeValidator`, and the methods therein get run.

Incase this is violated, ActiveRecord will throw an error right below the column name.

Hope this helps!