# Translate error messages using rails (I18n) Api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, rails-i18n

I am using rails internationalization api for activerecord translations .I am having trouble translating error messages.
How to translate multiple error messages from different files in my project?I am have files named `application_draft.rb,team.rb,user.rb,todo.rb` inside my `models` folder.I want to translate error messages in them ,here's my `en.yml` file:

```
errors:
        models:
         -team:
         -application_draft:
         -conference:
         -todo:
         -user:
            attributes:
              roles:
                too_many_reviewers: too many reviewers
                multiple_sel_error: must not be selected twice
                must_accepted: must have been accepted
                one_app_allowed: Only one application may be lodged
                confirmed_email_address: Please make sure every student confirmed the email address.
                wrong_date_sel: must be a later date than start date
                no_more_than_two: "there cannot be more than 2 students on a team."
                cannot_changed: can't be changed
```

I have implemented this code and throws error(means it did not work). Here's my one of `application_draft.rb` and `todo.rb` error code snippets:

#### application.rb:

```
def different_projects_required
  if project1 && project1 == project2
    errors.add(:projects, :multiple_sel_error)
  end
end
```

### todo.rb

```
def validate_number_of_reviewers
  errors.add(:user, :too_many_reviewers) if application.todos.count > 3
end
```

How to translate these both avoiding duplication errors?

Comment: Can you share the exact error message? Also, the `todo.rb` file snippet seems to have extra `end` at the bottom but i suppose you just copied it wrong

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ruby on Rails i18n - Want To Translate Custom Messages in Models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17935597/ruby-on-rails-i18n-want-to-translate-custom-messages-in-models)

Comment: @mbajur ,yes there is extra 'end' in todo.rb sorry for that.I am getting duplication error .My question is how do i translate error logs in both applcation_draft.rb and todo.rb without any duplication errors?I have used the above mentioned en.yml code but throws this error:
`Failure/Error: expect(todo.errors.messages).to eq({ user: ['too many reviewers'] })
     
       expected: {:user=>["too many reviewers"]}
            got: {:user=>["translation missing: en.activerecord.errors.models.todo.attributes.user.too_many_reviewers"]}`

Comment: @mbajur How do i translate messages in multiple models at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

Inherit it from activerecord:

```
en:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      models:
       -team:
       -application_draft:
       -conference:
       -todo:
       -user:
          attributes:
            roles:
              too_many_reviewers: too many reviewers
              multiple_sel_error: must not be selected twice
              must_accepted: must have been accepted
              one_app_allowed: Only one application may be lodged
              confirmed_email_address: Please make sure every student confirmed the email address.
              wrong_date_sel: must be a later date than start date
              no_more_than_two: "there cannot be more than 2 students on a team."
              cannot_changed: can't be changed
```

if it didn't work. I have another way. Try entering the translation in the method itself like below

```
    application.rb:

    def different_projects_required
      if project1 && project1 == project2
        errors.add(:projects, I18n.t('activerecord.errors.models.user.attributes.roles.multiple_sel_error'))
      end
    end

    todo.rb

    def validate_number_of_reviewers
      errors.add(:user, I18n.t('activerecord.errors.models.todo.attributes.roles.too_many_reviewers')) if application.todos.count > 3
    end
```