# How do I localize custom error messages in rails active record validations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord

To be specific I was trying to localize the *Custom Methods* example [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-methods). I found a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17935975/2924562) but I don't know how to pass that **:message** argument in **errors.add()** method. I tried doing something like this:

```
errors.add(:discount, message: :greater_than_value_error)
```

but it prints:

```
{:message=>:greater_than_value_error}
```

instead of printing the actual error message that was in the .yml file.

What should be the correct syntax here?

My .yml file looke like this (not sure whether this piece below is 100% accurate):

```
activerecord: #try to use activemodel here
  errors:
    models:
      invoice: # or namespace/model_name
        attributes:
          discount:
            greater_than_value_error: "can't be greater than total value"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try following `errors.add :field_name, :message` with rails 4.

```
errors.add(:discount, :greater_than_value_error)
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are writing custom validation then you need do actual translation,

```
errors.add(:discount, I18n.t(path_to_locale_text))
```

You can internationalize the standard validation messages like predefined validators `greater_than_value_error` only if you are using built in methods.

```
validates_numericality_of :discount :greater_than => limit
```

Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/4453350/1232447 for more details.